# Django ignores Form field required=True

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Form with two date fields, both required:

```
arrival_date = forms.DateField(
    required = True,
    widget = DateInput(attrs={
        "class": "input-small"
    }),
)
departure_date = forms.DateField(
    required = True,
    widget = DateInput(attrs = {
        "class": "input-small"
    })
)
```

As both dates involve some complex validation within a larger context, the form also has a `clean()` method which performs some additional checks on the dates:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(NewBookingForm3, self).clean()
    arrival_date = cleaned_data["arrival_date"]
    departure_date = cleaned_data["departure_date"]
    property_object = self.wizard.object.property
    try:
        validate_booked_dates(arrival_date, departure_date, property_object)
    except forms.ValidationError:
        del cleaned_data["arrival_date"]
        del cleaned_data["departure_date"]
        raise
    return cleaned_data
```

The problem now is that apparently the `clean()` method makes Django ignore `required=True` at the field level because when I submit the form without entering anything the `clean()` swings into action but crashes with a `KeyError` as the `cleaned_data` dictionary does not contain that key (which is understandable as I did not enter anything).

I would expect the field level check `required=True` to be performed BEFORE the `clean()` which would then flag that both fields need an entry of some sort and report that error back without running the `clean()`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field level check *is* performed before you get to `clean`. What's wrong is your assumption that `clean` wouldn't be called if any of those field checks failed. It is always called: otherwise how would any form level validation messages be created?

You need to protect yourself against the KeyError by using eg `form.cleaned_data.get()`.

Comment: I'm still confused. My assumption is that required=True would trigger a ValidationError exception when entering nothing in that particular field. This exception would then halt further execution of the form's validation process and report an error (via the form) BEFORE Django gets to execute the clean() method...

Comment: But it's the "halt" part of that which isn't true. `clean` is always called, because it has the chance to raise validation messages of its own, which may not have anything to do with any other validation failures: it would be odd to prevent, say, a "passwords do not match" error just because you failed to fill in a completely separate required field.

Comment: So, clean() gets called despite the fact that a field validation (required) raised an exception? I do not want to split hairs but are exceptions not there to block normal program flow to allow us to handle exceptional situations?